# Should I use NodeJS streams for small files?

Tags: node.js, node-streams

Does it always make sense to use the streams API for returning binary/blobs or are there disadvantages when using them for small files?

I am considering using a NodeJS proxy to return small images (~60KB) stored in S3. This is so I can add a layer of auth in NodeJS. From what I've read, NodeJS streams will be more memory efficient and faster for large files, however, I am wondering if there are any advantages or disadvantages when using streams for small files.

Comment: There's probably not much difference for small files.  As with all performance related things, if you really want to know, you should write code both ways and measure whatever parameters you think are most important in your comparison.  I could imagine a circumstance where `fs.promises.readFile()` was faster than a readstream for a small file, but it may also be not much difference.  Memory usage may be less without the stream because the stream may start with a larger buffer than 60kb, though you can customize that in the stream if you want.

Answer (score 1):

I would not use streams on this case. The file size is too small to justify the added complexity on the implementation.

If you have a hard requirement on performance, you might achieve better results optimizing the images rather than the transport.